# RTL8188SU USB dongle not started at boot

Tags: boot, wireless, realtek-wireless

I have installed Kubuntu 16.04 on my system. All is satisfactory except for the wireless dongle (RTL8188SU), which either has to be re-inserted after boot or `sudo service network-manager restart` run from Konsole to mount the dongle and connect to WiFi. Is there any way I can force dongle mounting during boot?

lsusb

```
 *-network               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 1f.6
   bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
   logical name: enp0s31f6
   version: 31
   serial: d0:50:99:93:65:be
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.8-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
   resources: irq:127 memory:df100000-df11ffff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@1:10
       logical name: wlxb4750e235176
       serial: b4:75:0e:23:51:76
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8712u ip=192.168.1.22 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

Comment: Would the following procedure apply to this issue?https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1509403

Answer (score 2):

Edit the following file using any of the following methods...

In `terminal`...

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/modules

sudo pico /etc/modules
```

Add the following line:

```
r8712u
```

Save the file and reboot, and your adapter should work fine.